# Constructing an orthogonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthogonality, orthonormal, orthogonal-matrices

> For any nonzero vector $v,\:w \in \mathbb{R}^n$, construct an orthogonal matrix $A$ such that $Av=\frac{\|v\|}{\|w\|}w$.

Here is something that came to my mind.

Let $v=\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2\end{bmatrix},\:w=\begin{bmatrix}
w_1\\
w_2\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

As, $A$ is an orthogonal matrix, its columns are orthogonal, and so it's similar to a matrix in the form of $\begin{bmatrix}
a&0\\
0&b
\end{bmatrix}$. Thus,

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a&0\\
0&b
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2\end{bmatrix}=\frac{\|v\|}{\|w\|}\begin{bmatrix}
w_1\\
w_n
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Hence, $a=\frac{\|v\|}{\|w\|}\frac{w_1}{v_1} $ and $b=\frac{\|v\|}{\|w\|}\frac{w_2}{v_2}.$

I'm wondering if my argument is valid and I can do the same for $\mathbb{R}^n.$

Comment: $A=\frac{\|v\|}{\|w\|}w$ makes no sense. The RHS is a vector.

Comment: I edited the equation in the problem statement to the most reasonable fix.  If this is incorrect, please undo my edit.

Comment: Also, your argument assumes both $v_1$ and $v_2$ are nonzero, which isn't a valid assumption.

Comment: @Aweygan Sorry, I missed $v$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $v,w$ are linearly indepedent. All vectors
of $\mathbf R^n$ are to be treated as column vectors.

1) Perform Gram--Schmidt process on the set $\{v,w\}$ to obtain an orthonormal
basis $(v_1,v_2)$ for the linear span $L=\langle v,w\rangle$
such that
$$
v_1 = \frac 1{|v|}v. 
$$

2) Perform Gram--Schmidt on the set $\{w,v\}$ to obtain an orthonormal
basis $(w_1,w_2)$ for $L$ such that
$$
w_1=\frac 1{|w|}w. 
$$

3) Extend the linear independent set $\{v_1,v_2\}$ to a basis $\mathcal B$
of $\mathbf R^n,$ say by adding to it some of the unit vectors
$e_i$ from the standard basis for $\mathbf R^n.$ Perform Gram--Schmidt
on $\mathcal B,$ followed by normalizing of all vectors to obtain
an orthnormal basis
$$
(v_1,v_2,v_3,\ldots,v_n)
$$
for $\mathbf R^n.$

4) Consider an orthonormal basis 
$$
(w_1,w_2,w_3,\ldots,w_n)=(w_1,w_2,v_3,\ldots,v_n)
$$
for $\mathbf R^n$ which is an extension of 
the linear independent set $\{w_1,w_2\}.$

5) Form the $(n\times n)$ matrices $V,W$ whose columns
are the vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3,\ldots,v_n$ and $w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n,$
respectively: 
$$
V=(v_1 \, v_2 \, \ldots v_n)
$$
and
$$
W=(w_1 \, w_2 \, \ldots w_n).
$$
Now both matrices $V,W$ are orthogonal, since each of them takes
the standard (orthonormal) basis $(e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n)$ to
an orthonormal basis. Say,
$$
V(e_1\, e_2 \, \ldots e_n)=(v_1 \, v_2 \, \ldots v_n)
$$

6) Finally, the matrix
$$
A=W V^{-1}
$$
takes the orthonormal basis $(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n)$
to the orthonormal basis $(w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n),$ and hence orthogonal.
In particular,
$$
A v_1=w_1,
$$
whence
$$
Av=A |v| v_1=|v| w_1=\frac{|v|}{|w|}w,
$$
as required.

Comment: Thanks! But what if $w, \:v$ aren't linearly independent?

Comment: :) Then they must be proporitional, and, since orthogonal matrices must preserve length, we would have that $v= \pm w.$ So either the identity matrix $I$ takes $v$ to $w,$ or $-I.$